# Maximum call stack size exceeded when syncing ArrayBuffer

Tags: dexie

I have a database which stores images (a thumbnail and a full size version) as ArrayBuffers.

When the dexie-cloud addon tries to sync the changes, it throws an error.

Thumbnails work fine because they have been resampled down to around 50-60 KB in size. However, the full size image (which can be 100-150 KB) fails in the b64encode function of base64.js:

```
Failed to sync client changes RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at b64encode (base64.js:22:41)
    at b64LexEncode (b64lex.js:3:21)
    at Object.replace (ArrayBuffer.js:6:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (TypesonSimplified.js:37:31)
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at Object.stringify (TypesonSimplified.js:33:31)
    at syncWithServer.ts:60:16
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (tslib.es6.js:73:58)
```

specially at this line:

```
return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, ArrayBuffer.isView(b) ? b : new Uint8Array(b)));
```

Are there any work arounds for larger ArrayBuffers?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the bug report! I've filed it as an issue in github: https://github.com/dexie/Dexie.js/issues/1643

There's no workaround for the moment. Please subscribe to the issue on github to get notified when it is resolved or get some progress.